# XCode - file not found in document directory

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am having random error while reading saved photos from document directory in iPhone. I save photos taken from my app to document directory and then read it from there next time when user come back. However, after XCode 6 & base SDK change to 8.1, this document directory path keeps changing. So sometime I found photos and sometime not.

I read few posts online thats says that not Apple differentiate App from Data and that's why this issue coming up.  Anyone has any thoughts on this? Any solution?

This is how I save file to document Directory

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"key"];
[image writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

And this is how I read it:

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"key"];
UIImage *cellImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Check the return value of `writeToFile:`. Use the Devices window of Xcode and look at the contents of the Documents folder on your iPhone after writing the image to see if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Product - Scheme - Edit Scheme - Options - Working Directory and specify working directory

Comment: @MeetShah there must be for sure

Comment: @PutinHuylo looks like it's an iOS target

Comment: nope.. I dont see it there. I have XCode 6.1. Can I set or change working directory from anywhere else like from build settings?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.